# How to get the email address from Reply to field in office 360 using python?

Tags: office365

**I haven been stuck in the problem of how to get the email address of  Reply to field in python. I have tried many things but haven't been able to work with any of them. Anyone has any idea?**

Comment: What is Office 360?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.